# $f(a x) = f(x)$ implies its enough to consider $|x| \in [1, a]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In a proof I read, the authors defined a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and claimed that since $f(ax) = f(x), a>1$ it is enough to consider only the $|x|\in [1,a]$. The authors then proceed and use this fact to proof that $f$ is bounded from above.

Can somebody please explain why this is true? Does this hold in general? Why can I ignore $|x| \in [0, 1)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(0)=\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}0=0.$ "it is enough to consider only the $|x|\in [1,a]$": enough for what aim?

Comment: If $f(ax) = f(x)$, then $F(y)= f(e^y)$ is $(\log a)$-periodic, so it is enough to consider $F$ on the interval $[0,\log a]$

Comment: @AnneBauval to show that the function $f$ is bounded from above. You are right for the specific example $f(0)=0$, however I wonder if this is also true for general functions.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't think this adresses the question. The OP seems aware it is enough to consider $f$ for $|x|\in[1,a]\cup\{0\}$ and is asking why $0$ can be forgotten.

Comment: @stish If you find an upper bound $M$ for $f$ on $(-a,-1]\cup[1,a)$ hence on $\Bbb R^*,$ the bound $M':=\max(M,f(0))$ will also work for $f(0).$

Comment: @stish Since your formula was just an example, I think it obscured your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(ax) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $a > 1$, note that $$f(x) = f(a^{n}x) = f(a^{-n}x)\qquad\text{for all }n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Now, suppose you want to evaluate $f$ at some $x_0 > a$. Then, of course, $x_0 \in [a^k,a^{k+1})$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., $\frac{x_0}{a^k} \in [1,a]$. Thus, $$f(x_0) = f\left(\frac{x_0}{a^k}\right) = f(z_0)$$ where $z_0 = \frac{x_0}{a^k} \in [1,a]$. An exactly similar thing can be done when $x \in (0,1)$. This ensures that if $x > 0$, it is sufficient to focus on the interval $[1,a]$.

Once again, an almost identical calculation can be carried out when $x <0$. In that case, it is sufficient to look at $[-a,-1]$.

The case where $x = 0$ should be tackled separately, I believe. If it is given that $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$, then by continuity, $f(x) = f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Otherwise, I believe that $f(0)$ should be defined separately. In that case, we can say that it is sufficient to work with the case $|x| \in \{0\} \cup [1,a]$.

---

**Note:** Another thing that is worth mentioning is that if we know that $f$ is continuous in $[1,a]$, we can conclude that $f$ is bounded above for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, thanks to the above argument. In that case, $f$ will be bounded above by $$\max\left\{f(0),\max_{x \in [1,a]} f(x)\right\}.$$